# Error loading Android emulator for Appcelerator (Ti Studio)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to build the project for one of the labs on the Titanium training website. The emulator itself starts and I'm able to navigate to various parts such as downloads or the browser. My app however never makes it onto the emulator and I don't know why. The following is the compiler output in Ti Studio 3.1.2:

```
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2596, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host, profiler_host=profiler_host)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2314, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.manifest_changed = self.generate_android_manifest(compiler)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 975, in generate_android_manifest
[ERROR]     self.generate_localizations()
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 1501, in generate_localizations
[ERROR]     doc = parseString(contents.encode("utf-8"))
[ERROR]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1338515509\python\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1921, in parseString
[ERROR]     return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1338515509\python\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
[ERROR]     return builder.parseString(string)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1338515509\python\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
[ERROR]     parser.Parse(string, True)
[ERROR] ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

EDIT: Found it, simple syntax issue in an xml file used for internationalization...

```
[ERROR] ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, simple syntax issue in an xml file used for internationalization...

[ERROR] ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0